# restricted content with assisted service mode

Tags: spartacus-storefront

in our spartacus SAP commcerce project we have restricted CMS navigation nodes which are only visible for some user groups. If we now log in with the assisted service mode for a user which has access to this navigatin node when he loggs hin normally, these navigation nodes are not visible in ASM mode on behalf of this user.

This is also already documented as limits of spartacus documentation https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/asm/#limitations:

*Limitations*

*ASM customer emulation does not work with CMS content rules and restrictions in Spartacus. If there are content rules or restrictions that are normally applied based on a customer’s ID, or the customer’s group ID, these rules and restrictions are not applied during an ASM customer emulation. The CMS endpoints instead provide content based on what the customer support agent is permitted to see.*

*To display CMS content, Spartacus relies on the CMS endpoints from OCC. When requests are sent, the CMS endpoints do not accept a userId parameter that could define the emulated user (that is, the customer). The CMS endpoints only recognize the authenticated user as the sender of requests, and in ASM customer emulation sessions, the authenticated user is the customer support agent.*

*The following OCC CMS endpoints work only for the authenticated user:*

```
/{baseSiteId}/cms/components
/{baseSiteId}/cms/components/{componentId}
/{baseSiteId}/cms/pages
/{baseSiteId}/cms/pages/{pageId}
/{baseSiteId}/cms/sitepages*
```

*OCC CMS endpoints do not accept a userId parameter, so it is not possible for an emulated customer to trigger CMS rules and restrictions during an ASM emulation session.*

For our customer this functionality is critical. Is there any plan within Spartacus to provide this functionality? Is there already a timeline for this feature?

Thanks,#
Nadja

Comment: Dear Spartacus Develper Team,
according to your website, this is the place to go for support. Then it would also be great to get any feedback. Or do I need to use a different channel?

Comment: Dear Spartacus Developer Team, who can I contact to get an answer?